# Magento 2: How to get last inserted custom table Id without saving new item?

Tags: magento2, blocks, model, table

I want to get the last inserted id to my block without adding new data into the table. I want to use this value to automatically filled in my phtml file. I tried getId and it's not working. I just need the last id. Can anyone help?

Comment: uhmm ok, but why? normally, you would set the ID column as autoincrement so you don't have to worry about 'what is the next ID to insert here'.

Comment: actually i want auto-increment in two colums and when i tried to create using dbschema,its saying that auto icrement is set only for one column. so thats why im going for another method:)

Comment: i see. well, in that case, you either call last_insert_id() method (https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_mysql_last_insert_id.asp) ooooor you create a stored procedure that you call in order to increment the second column :D :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the answer by creating helper class

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Helper;

use vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Collection_Folder\CollectionFactory;
class Helper extends \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $modelFactory
    ) {
        $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLatestid()
    {
        $model = $this->modelFactory->create(); 
        $data = $model->load();
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $id = $item->getData('id');
        }
        return $id;
    }

}
```

This way we can get last inserted Id..

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
protected $_resource;
public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
   ...
   ) {
   $this->_resource = $resource;
}

$connection = $this->_resource->getConnection();
$yourLastAddedId = $connection->lastInsertId('your_table_name');
```

or use below

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('your_table_name');
$yourLastAddedId = $connection->lastInsertId($tableName);
```

hope its helps you:)

Comment: sorry, it didn't work for me

Comment: `$this->getConnection()` is not accessible on this

Comment: @zaheerabbas answer updated

Comment: @GohilRajesh it will always return 0.As there isn't any function in that class

Comment: check another added code. try to first achive through object manager

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a custom SQL statement

```
protected $resourceConnection;
public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
   ...
   ) {
   $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}

 $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
 $sql = "select id FROM customtable order by id desc limit 1";
 $latestIdResults= $connection->fetchAll($sql);
 
 $latestId = 0;

 foreach($latestIdResults as $id){
          $latestId = $id["id"];                        
 }
```

$latestId will be your lastest incremented id :) There are mysql functions for this but this is one way to do it if your keys and tables are heavily customized.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$lastId = $this->resource->getConnection()->fetchOne(
                $this->resource->getConnection()
                    ->select()
                    ->from('my_table', ['id'])
                    ->order('id DESC')
            )
```